# I am Using URL to get the Location Search of Google Maps for Android - URL type comes in API v2 or v3

Tags: java, json, google-maps, url, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am working on 2.3.3 with Google Maps API level 10.

I used the below code to get the location entered by USER.

The URL which I used is belongs to Google MAPs API v2 or v3.

```
public static JSONObject getLocationInfo(String address)
{
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                                  + address
                                  + "ka&sensor=false");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1)
        {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try
    {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
```

After executing this, another method converts that JSONObject into a GeoPoint.

```
public static GeoPoint getGeoPoint(JSONObject jsonObject)
{
    Double lon = new Double(0);
    Double lat = new Double(0);

    try
    {
        lon = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
              .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
              .getDouble("lng");

        lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
              .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
              .getDouble("lat");
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lon * 1E6));
}
```

Using the above code - I am not able to get the location with PIN code Search.  How do I get the location with a pin code Search?

Comment: Friends - now i understood that URL is not related to Version  - i am calling web service - please give me an idea of how to search using PIN NUmber